# Django not loading some templates on my server

Tags: python, django, web-services, heroku, http-status-code-404

Currently using heroku server to test my code but I can’t seem to get it work because it working on my local host . The issue is some pages are not loading and i have run heroku run bash to check and the html existed

but on server it shows [image: On the server]

while on local host it shows
[image: On my local host]

Comment: Compare the directory that Heroku is trying to use vs. what you use locally, they are likely not the same - hence the error

Comment: Sure i have actually done that with heroku run bash

Answer (score 0):

Fix the issue I realized I named the template name folder  on some code base on caps which works on local server

```
class ShippingRoutineDeleteView(StaffAndLoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = ShippingRoutine
    success_url = reverse_lazy('order:dashboard_routine_list_create')
    template_name = 'Dashboard/routine/routine_delete.html'
    context_object_name = 'item'
```

so I change it to this which is the correct one because my folder directory is not on caps

```
class ShippingRoutineDeleteView(StaffAndLoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = ShippingRoutine
    success_url = reverse_lazy('order:dashboard_routine_list_create')
    template_name = 'dashboard/routine/routine_delete.html'
    context_object_name = 'item'
```

Comment: It’s more of like if u use windows it works though if the director is on caps that’s why I never noticed it on local testing